# How to aggregate sum of several previous aggregated values in django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm, django-aggregation

In use: django 3.2.10, postgresql 13.4
I have next query set with aggregation function Count

```
queryset = Model.objects.all().aggregate(
    trues=Count('id', filter=Q(criteria=True)),
    falses=Count('id', filter=Q(criteria=False)),
)
```

What I want:

```
queryset = Model.objects.all().aggregate(
    trues=Count('id', filter=Q(criteria=True)),
    falses=Count('id', filter=Q(criteria=False)),
    total=trues+falses, <--------------THIS
)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is little thing you can do after aggregation, as it returns a python dict object.

I do understand your example here is not your real situation, as you can simply do

```
Model.objects.aggregate(
    total = (Count('id', filter=Q(criteria=True))
        + Count('id', filter=Q(criteria=False)))
)
```

What I want to say is Django provides `.values().annotate()` to achieve `GROUP BY` clause as in sql language.

Take your example here

```
queryset = Model.objects.values('criteria').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

queryset here is still a 'QuerySet' object, and you can further modify the queryset like

```
queryset = queryset.aggregate(
    total=Sum('count')
)
```

Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you want the total number of false and true criteria so you can simply do as follow

```
queryset = Model.objects.all().filter(
           Q(criteria=True) | Q(criteria=False)).count()
```

or you can use (not recommended except you want to show something in the middle)

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Case, Count, F, Max, Min, Prefetch, Q, Sum, When

query = Model.objects.annotate(trues=Count('id',filter=Q(criteria=True)), 
falses=Count('id',filter=Q(criteria=False))).annotate(trues_false=F('trues')+F('falses')).aggregate(total=Sum('trues_false'))
```